# How to achieve something like a macro in a bash script

Tags: bash

I wrote a library function which processes an argument list and allows for easy querying of options, etc. (The full source is [here](https://github.com/tomocafe/bash-boost/blob/main/src/cli/arg.sh), but I hope it shouldn't be necessary to read through the details for this particular question.)

Essentially you pass in a list of args, usually `"$@"`, to a function, and any other non-option arguments (positionals) get passed on to another list called `BB_POSARGS`.

To make it easier for the programmer using the library, I generally suggest overwriting the argument list after parsing as follows: `set -- "${BB_POSARGS[@]}"`.

```sh
bb_parseargs "$@" # here $@ are the original arguments
set -- "${BB_POSARGS[@]}" # now $@ only contains positional arguments
unset BB_POSARGS # clean up
# Check options, flags, etc. with bb_getopt, bb_checkopt
for things in "$@"; do
  # this won't contain any options, flags, etc.
  echo "doing something with $thing"
done
```

Ideally I could replace this boilerplate:

```sh
bb_parseargs "$@" # here $@ are the original arguments
set -- "${BB_POSARGS[@]}" # now $@ only contains positional arguments
unset BB_POSARGS # clean up
```

with one function, alias, macro, etc. named `bb_processargs`:

```sh
bb_processargs # parses $@; afterward, $@ only contains positional arguments
```

I don't think `bb_processargs` can be a function because using `set --` within a function only changes *its own* argument list, not its calling parent's.

Aliases don't seem to support arguments or propagate the `"$@"`.

Is there any way to bundle the `set --` with the function call?

Comment: There's [`BASH_ARGV`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-BASH_005fARGV) and [`BASH_ARGC`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-BASH_005fARGC), but they're only available in debug mode, it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you just define the QOL function as an alias, something like this:

```
bash-5.1$ alias my_thing='echo $@;set -- a b c'
bash-5.1$ set -- 1 2 3
bash-5.1$ my_thing 
1 2 3
bash-5.1$ my_thing 
a b c
```

See how `my_thing` uses `$@` and then sets the new argument list, in your case you would use something like:

```
alias bb_processargs='bb_parseargs "$@";set -- "${BB_POSARGS[@]}";unset BB_POSARGS'
```

Comment: I thought I’d tried exactly that, but maybe I forgot to use single quotes. I’m guessing that’s the key?

Comment: If you used double quotes, then `$@` would expand when the alias is created, using single quotes, will allow `$@` to expand when the alias is called.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I was under the wrong impression using single quotes here would result in the raw string `$@`. I’m pleased to be wrong about that!